# Product custom options adding radio button slects only one button in magento2

Tags: magento2

I have added the radio button for the product custom options, But My requirement is selects only one Radio button in magento2

please find the screen shot:

[image]

Comment: :How have you added radio button here?

Answer (score 0):

You have to give them the same name for both the radio buttons.

```
<input type="radio" name="optionTitle" />
```